# Maximum possible number of extrema of the function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, irreducible-polynomials, maxima-minima

Consider a function :

$$ f(x)= P(x)e^{-(x^4+2x^2)} $$in the domain $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$, $P(x)$ is any polynomial of degree $k$. What is the maximum possible number of extrema of the function.

My attempt : I differentiated the function and finally got a polynomial of degree $k+3$ set to zero ( condition for extremum). Therefore, I conclude that maximum possible extrema should be $k+3$ corresponding to k+3 roots of the polynomial which i get after differentiating. But the answer given in the book is $k+1$. Please help me understand this? What am i missing?

Comment: Please edit the post to show how you obtained a polynomial of degree $k+3$. It may be possible that there is some issue with your working, for example.

Comment: differentiating we get f'(x)=[P(x)e^-(...)(-4x^3-4x)]+P'(x)e^-(...), after setting it to zero ( condition for extrema), e^(..) can't be zero there we r left with a polynomial of degree k+3 set to zero which can at max have k+3 roots. I am sorry for not being clear in my writing, i am new here.

Comment: "any polynomial of degree $k$" --- I assume we're excluding [$k=-1$ and $k=-\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Degree_of_the_zero_polynomial)?

Comment: @FarmanUllah For a polynomial of degree $k \geq 1$ is really the maximal number of extrema $k+3.$ But if $k=0, P(x)=c,$ is $f'(x)=-4cx(x^2+1),$ which has only one real root.

Answer (score 1):

If you differentiate it then you will get a term in multiplication $4x^3 +4x =4x(x^2+1)$ now $x^2 +1$ has no real roots so effectively differentiation will be zero for only $k+1$ times.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math Stack! That's a nice answer, I'm sure there will be more, but you should learn how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Before differentiating assume that the polynomial P*k*(x) is of zero-order i.e *k*=0 (P(x)=constant). Now upon differentiating it with respect to x and equating it to zero, you'll only get one term i.e. P(*k=0*)(x).(4x^3+4x).e^(f(x)) = 0.
Now as e^(f(x)) can't be zero. Hence P(*k=0*)(x).(4x^3+4x)=0. Upon simplifying 4x(x^2+1)=0 as x^2+1=0 doesn't have any real solution. So x=0.
Now from this you can interpret this that for a zero-order polynomial you are getting one extrema. Hence for "*k*" order of polynomial you'll get "*k*+1" extrema.

Comment: Please excuse my writing as I am new here and currently trying to write a good answer.